# how return an output type date in web services? any solution

Tags: java, web-services

i try to return an output (type date ) in a web service but i receive a weird result

```
@WebMethod 
public Date testDate(String arg) throws ParseException{
    System.out.println(arg);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(arg);
    Date dat = sdf.parse(arg);
    System.out.println("date");

    System.out.println(dat);
    return dat;
}
```

this my input 16/08/2013 11:05:03 but i receive this output

```
<return>1970-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</return>
```

Expected output should contain "16/08/2013 11:05:03".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the string date "arg" for create the format, in the constructor of format you must put the format

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Date now = new Date();
String dateString = now.toString();
System.out.println(" 1. " + dateString);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
System.out.println(" 3. " + format.format(now));
}
1.    Mon Aug 06 11:12:00 ART 2012
3.    Mon ago 06 11:12:00 ART 2012
```